# String Manipulation in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, python-re

Hey guys I have a quick question regarding the string manipulation in pandas dataframe.

Suppose we have 2 columns looks like this:

[image]

**Question:**

How I can keep only the string part for each cell and delete the **[' ']**?

Thank you so much for your help! I am looking forward to hearing your brilliant idea!

Comment: Is `['AK']` the list of strings or the string `"['AK']"`?

Comment: What have you tried. Please try to post if you attempted to solve this so others can think of better solution and correct in your solution.

Comment: @QuangHoang is a list like an object in a string. I encounter it in some previous projects. think it will be an interesting question.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I definitly will do that! thank you for your suggestion! All three solutions below provided a great opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use regex to replace all non alphanumeric characters

```
print(df)

   State         City
0  ['AK']  ['Yakutat']
1  ['AK']   ['Apache']
```

Solution

```
df=df.replace(regex='[^\w]',value='')

print(df)



 State     City
0    AK  Yakutat
1    AK   Apache
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this is a brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0):

Depends if the values in each of your cells are strings with brackets `"['AK']"` or actual lists: `['AK']`.

If they are strings with brackets on either side, we can strip bracket characters from both sides:

```
df["State"] = df["State"].str.strip("[]")
df["City"] = df["City"].str.strip("[]")
```

If they are lists with you can join them with a comma to turn them into a string

```
df["State"] = df["State"].str.join(", ")
df["City"] = df["City"].str.join(", ")
```

Comment: This is also a great idea. similar to the second one. brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
df['City']=df['City'].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2])
df['State']=df['State'].apply(lambda x: x[2:-2])
```

Comment: That is a great brilliant idea! Learned a lot from all the brilliant comments. I assume it will be a bit faster than regex.